# How can I check for valid promo code in my Ionic 3 Angular app against the database table?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid, mobile-development

I am getting the data from the user in a new user registration screen. After clicking the register button, the data are getting saved in the database. I am using an input field called promocode, to check for the user's promo code. Here's what I need:

I am having a set of promocodes already in a database table. If the user types a promocode, and if the particular code exists in my database table, it can allow the user to register in my app. Suppose if the user is typing a promocode that is not in my database table, it should display toast message as invalid promocode and so that the user is not allowed to register. This promocode validation should happened after the user fill all the details and after clicking the submit button.

Here's what I have tried so far:

In my HTML:

```
<ion-item>
<ion-icon name="ios-hand" class="iconstyle" item-left></ion-icon>

<ion-label color = "textcolor" floating>Reseller Promo Code</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" class="textcolor" [(ngModel)] = "vm.promocode" formControlName = "promocode" maxlength = "15"  tabindex="2" (keyup)="moveFocus($event,query, false)" >
</ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

In my ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {SignupService} from '../../services/signup.service';
import { MessageService } from '../../services/message.service';
import { BroadCastService } from '../../services/broadcast.service';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';
import { Signup } from '../../models/signup';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
  providers: [SignupService]
})
export class SignupPage{
formsignup: FormGroup;

submit(){


  if (this.formsignup.valid) {
    this.signupservice.savesignup(this.vm).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.message.alert("Your account has been created successfully");
      this.resetForm(this.formsignup);
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
    });


  }
  else{
  this.validateFormControl(this.formsignup);
}
}
```

This is my service.ts file where I am posting the user details to the server and saving it in the database.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";


@Injectable()
export class SignupService {
    constructor(private dataservice: DataService) {

    }

    savesignup(formdetails:any){
        return this.dataservice.post('/api/Login/Register', formdetails);
    }
}
```

In my model class I have used this promocode as follows:

signup.ts:

```
export class Signup{
promocode: string;
```

Now everything is working fine. All my data are saving in the database and  I can able to login with the registered account. But I don't know how to implement this functionality. I am new to Ionic.

Comment: What is the server side code ? If the promo code is included in formdetails, then you have to process the promo code on your server and then return to the app if yes or not the registration is accepted. `this.dataservice.post('/api/Login/Register', formdetails);` will return this answer

Comment: @saperlipopette., We can't able to validate it right? We will just send the details right?

Comment: Please show your server side code. But yes you should be able to validate it

Comment: @saperlipopette., Yes friend, but they're asking me to send the promocode as a paramater, so that they'll validate it in server side and stores it in a database. I don't know how to send it as a parameter

Comment: `vm` is containing the promocode right ? In your code you use `vm.promocode` as the model for your promo input. And then you’re sending the whole `vm` object to your API, so you should be able to get this value from your server no ?

Comment: @saperlipopette., we were checking it before sometime, they told me that we didn't receive your promocode to the server side here, pls send the promocode value as a parameter.  all other values like first name and last name has been going from here, but not the promocode i don't know how to send it

Comment: Where is vm declared in your ts file ? What about the others inputs of the form (name, last name etc) ?

Comment: @saperlipopette ok wait... let me post it here:
export class Signup{
    title: string;
    gender: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    dateOfBirth: string;
    email: string;
    primaryContactNumber:string;
    identificationNumber: string;
    mobileNumber: string;
    landlinenumber: string;
    promocode: string;
    
    password: string;
    confirmpassword: string;
    
    






}

Comment: Please edit your post so it can be readable

Answer (score 0):

You can (or "should") create your PromoService (Provider) and a method that should look something like this should work.

```
public GetPromo(code: string): Promise<any> { //Can be strongly typed if you want to implement a class or interface for a Promo
    var url = '/GetPromo'; //your endpoint's url.
    var args: RequestOptionsArgs = {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            code : code //Your parameter. You can add more properties for multiple parameters.
        }
    };

    return this.http.request(url, args).map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
}
```

For post requests, parameters are attached to `body`.

```
var args: RequestOptionsArgs = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
        code : code //Your parameter. You can add more properties for multiple parameters.
    }
};
```